# deleting or renaming column in sqlite

Tags: java, sqlite

I named one of my columns "from" and it's causing errors. Do I rename or delete the column and I am using sqlite database system. This was what I tried and it did not work.

```
INSERT INTO passengerinfonew(driverid, name, surname, age, username, password, gender, marital_status, fromDest, toDest)
SELECT driverid, name, surname, age, username, password, gender, marital_status, from, to
FROM passengerinfonews;
```

this was after creating a temporary table

Answer (score 2):

You can escape the column's name by surrounding it with double quotes (`"`) - just use `"from"` instead of `from` and you should be fine.